# How could I add a 3D Revit Building in my webscene

Tags: arcgis-online, web-scene, revit

I heard about the new integration between GIS & BIM ,I want to know how I can put my 3d model from Revit to a Webscene on arcgis Online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

As written [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/revit/what-is-revit-data-.htm), it is possible to connect directly from ArcGIS Pro to .RVT files.

**Original**

As far as I know you need tooling to convert your Revit model to a File Geodatabase.

See [Data Interoperability extension](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-interoperability/what-is-the-data-interoperability-extension-.htm). This is [Safe Software's](https://www.safe.com/) FME (Feature Manipulating Engine) integrated in ArcMap. ([How to](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000017416).) Personally I prefer to use FME in its non integrated form, FME Desktop.

My current workflow is:

- Export from Revit to IFC using Revit.
- Convert from IFC to File GeoDatabase using FME.
- Export from File GeoDatabase to Scene Layer Package using ArcGIS Pro.
- Upload Scene Layer Package to AGOL.

In the release of FME Desktop 2019 it will be possible to read native Revit files, without the need of export to IFC.

Comment: Can I Export from File GeoDatabase to Scene Layer Package using QGIS instead of ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: As the format is open, in theory yes, if someone built the tool.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to convert the data to a feature class in a geodatabase. If you want to add a 3D Revit model into a WebScene use ArcGIS Pro 2.3 with the Create Building Scene Layer package tool. Simply add the Revitt model into your Scene in Pro through Add Data button and then you will run the GP tool. This will package the model into the slpk which you can upload to ArcGIS  Online(organizational account that supports publishing scene layers) and add the published building scene layer into a web scene. Then use the building explorer widget to enable/disable the layers or check out the slice widget to look inside the building. You can also store the visibility property for the sub layers in slides so you can make a demo which navigates the building and makes it easy for users that might not be comfortable navigating in 3D and controlling layer visibility.